# California: "For quality assurance, this phone call is being recorded"

Tags: california, phonecall, wiretapping

In California, it is illegal to record phone calls without the consent of all parties involved.

However, when you call corporate phone number, you often get a message to the effect of "For quality assurance reasons, this call is being recorded."

Isn't this illegal, if you are calling from California? What can be done to prevent the company from recording (other than hanging up - let's assume there's a reason you needed to call them)?

Comment: If you believe this question has already been answered here, you are welcome to flag it as a duplicate. That you appear to have zero possible duplicate options to present, would indicate that in fact it has not been "answered *ad nauseam*" as you claim.

Comment: For example, you have paid for an insurance policy or warranty, and the only way to make a claim is to phone them.

Comment: I wonder if this gives you the right to record the call as well.

Comment: @Matt As long as you state you're doing so (or know for sure that all parties are in [single-party consent states](http://www.dmlp.org/legal-guide/recording-phone-calls-and-conversations),) then sure.

Comment: As long as you aren't saying anything incriminating or giving out personal information, there's almost no reason to worry about stuff like this.

Comment: @LogicalBranch True, I'm just getting hung up on silly trifles like human dignity and basic rights.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The recording is not illegal because you've been told it would happen, and by not hanging up, you've agreed to have a conversation that can be recorded.

This was determined in *Kearney v. Salomon Smith Barney, Inc.* applying the exception of Penal Code 632 that communications are not considered confidential if there is a reasonable expectation that the call will be overheard or recorded - being explicitly told that the call will be recorded makes this true.

[It would not be illegal for them to only record their own statements during the call](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/), nor for you to record only your statements, either. In particular, the company is allowed to record the part of the call where they make this statement, as they are not recording a conversation, only their own (likely pre-recorded) statement (again?). Indeed, including their statement **about** the recording **in** the recording is common practise partly for protection against claims that the other party was not informed of the recording occurring.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94299/discussion-on-answer-by-nij-california-for-quality-assurance-this-phone-call).

Answer (score 28):

### No, it’s not illegal

You have been informed that the call will be recorded. If you continue with the call having that knowledge you have consented to the recording. If you don’t consent you can hang up.

If you need to communicate with them and don’t want to be recorded, do it in writing or in person.

Comment: Isn't writing also subject to being recorded?

Comment: @Consis if you mean recorded in the sense of creating a record then yes. But that is not the same as an audio recording of people speaking - your letter or email is unlikely to record you flying off the handle in rage. Also, there is no law against your telephone partner taking notes and, if they know shorthand, those notes could be verbatim.

Comment: @Consis In particular, there is no right to communicate with someone without them recording what you say, but rather only that they can't record a private conversation _without your knowledge_. As Nij's answer notes, the law itself explicitly excludes from protection any circumstance wherein the parties to the communication may reasonable expect the communication could be overheard or recorded. Explicitly telling you that it may be recorded would certainly create such an excluded circumstance.

Comment: By definition, the listener needs to "record" at least some part of the audio stream (in his/her brain) in order to make an intelligent response to it. And it's impossible to forget things using only one's own willpower, though drugs such as sedatives may inhibit creating a "permanent" memory of events. This may explain why call center operators often seem to behave as if they are under the influence of medication, of course :)

Comment: @Consis It would be hard to argue that someone had not "consented" to writing a letter or email and then sending it! Of course of someone else impersonated them in sending a written message, that is a different legal issue.

Comment: "consent" seems overly strong.  For example, if I state "by continuing to read this comment, you agree to sell me your home for 1 dollar US.  If you read this sentence, obviously you already consented to the previous agreement."  I'm not certain any "consent" is required here.  And if not, and simply placing an ultimatum in a sentence is enough for other people to consent to arbitrary deals, I gotta find a bunch of US dollars and collect my houses!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94273/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-california-for-quality-assurance-this-phone-ca).

Comment: @Yakk You are conflating *consent* with *agreement*. In the first case, we are talking about consent that is a legal requirement for an action to not be illegal. The consenter is not giving up any consideration. In the second case you are attempting to form a *contract*, which means the other rules of contract also apply and this contract would fail for lack of intention. It's obvious I have no intention to enter into a contract with you by reading your comment. In any case I don't think any judge would accept merely reading an offer as a mode of acceptance, regardless of your wording.

Comment: @Yakk Perhaps "notice" is better framing than consent. When they inform you that your call may be recorded, they are providing you notice that your call won't be as confidential as you may think (as CA law puts it: "circumstance in which the parties to the communication may reasonably expect that the communication may be overheard or recorded"). The law doesn't require consent; it just requires that your expectations be set appropriately, and giving you notice that others may be listening is sufficient to do that.

Answer (score -2):

If they began recording your statements before informing you of the call being recorded, then you could argue that part of your conversation was recorded without consent.

Informing you that the call is being recorded implies consent if you proceed with the call.

If they began recording the conversation at the moment right before informing of you of recording, then this is likely a legal implementation of recording a phone call.

However, if you were to have spoken simultaneously during their statement that the call is being recorded and that was recorded, you could argue that you did not grant consent to them recording that statement. Also, because you interrupted their statement that the call is being recorded, you could argue that you did not grant consent because you were speaking while being issued this statement, which implies that you did not properly receive their statement its in entirety.

Basically, it's probably completely fine that they are recording these phone calls when stating that they are doing so. However, there are ways to argue against it if you ever had to in a court of law.